# C++ Return value type does not match the function type

Tags: c++, matrix

I'm trying to return a matrix and in the method it's giving me the error: Return value type does not match the function type.

Here is the matrix:

```
float obstaculos[20][4];
```

Here is the method:

```
float** getObstaculos() {
    return obstaculos;
}
```

Do you know what the problem may be?

Comment: Have you tried returning array of pointers instead of pointer to pointer or even just a simple 2D-float matrix?

Comment: `obstaculos` is of type `float[20][4]`, not `float**`. These are two different types.

Comment: You have made the incorrect (but common) assumption that since an array can be degraded to a pointer, a 2D array must be convertible to a pointer to a pointer. There is no pointer to a pointer anywhere in this code.

Comment: `return &obstaculos[0]`

Comment: @TomaszKłak: although this may get you past the type check, it almost certainly still does the wrong thing!

Comment: I have no idea what does Adam Silva wants to do, like all of us ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float obstaculos[20][4];
```

… is an array of arrays of `float` values. Due to `sizeof` requirements it's a contiguous sequence of `float` values in memory.

```
float**
```

… is a pointer to a pointer to `float`. The single sequence of `float` values (the `obstaculos` matrix) can naturally convert to a direct pointer (namely to the first item), but there is no pointer stored in that memory that you can get a pointer to pointer to.

So, one possibility is to do

```
using Row = float[4];
Row obstaculos[20];

Row* getObstaculos() {
    return obstaculos;
}
```

But it would be better to define a Matrix, e.g.

```
#include <array>

using Row = std::array<float, 4>;
using Matrix = std::array<Row, 20>;

Matrix obstaculos;

Matrix* getObstaculos() {
    return &obstaculos;
}
```

If you really need an array of pointers, then you might want to make the matrix originally of that form.

---

Amendment:
Here's one way to compute an array of pointers to the rows, if you need that:

```
using Row_data_pointers = std::array<float*, std::tuple_size<Matrix>::value>;

auto data_pointers( Matrix& m )
    -> Row_data_pointers
{
    Row_data_pointers result;
    for( int i = 0; i < int( std::tuple_size<Row_data_pointers>::value ); ++i )
    {
        result[i] = &m[i][0];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While `float*` and `float[N]` are *similar* types (they can be used in a similar way, and the first can be implicitly be initialized from the second), but this doesn't hold for **nested arrays**.

### Why is this so?

The type `float**` is a pointer to pointer. When you use it like a 2D array / matrix (with two subscript operators being applied), the first pointer is expected to point to an **array of pointers** which point to more arrays (e.g. to individual rows).

However, `float[N][M]` is a **contiguous** block of memory for the whole matrix. There is no array of (row) pointers, and none can be created implicitly by casting to `float**`, thus this cast isn't possible by the standard.

### What can you do?

You can return a **reference to a multidimensional array**. For this, first create a typedef for your matrix: `typedef float matrix[20][4];` and then use the return type `matrix&`

Or **avoid nested arrays**. Use a one dimensional array and compute the index when accessing (e.g. `matrix[row * N + col]` instead of `matrix[row][col]`). Hide this index computation in a matrix class, which returns a helper object for the first `operator[]`.

Better: **Use a Linear Algebra library** for handling matrices, for example Eigen.